# In ember-states and ember-views, is there any default targeting like defaultResponder of sproutcore?

Tags: ember.js

I see Ember.RootResponder in many places in ember source code, but almost without exception it is commented out.  Is RootResponder the "new" defaultResponder and is it still under development?  Tips on other sproutcore/embers techniques decoupling views and state also welcome!-)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a `RootResponder` in Ember. We have an `EventDispatcher` instead.

[EventDispatcher source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/system/event_dispatcher.js)